# Typescript type predicate over types formed by conditional

Tags: typescript, generics, predicate, typing

I have this type

```
type Test<T extends "a"|"b"> = T extends "a" ? number : string;
```

and I'm trying to use the `is` keyword to determine the type of a value of type Test to use it in the right way later like so

```
function ValueIsNumber<T extends "a"|"b">(value:Test<T>):value is number // Here an error is raised
{
    return(typeof value === "number");
}

function myFunc<T extends "a"|"b">(value:Test<T>):number
{
    if (ValueIsNumber(value))
        return (value + 1);

    return (0);
}
```

The error says:

[errorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0C6S.png)

I understand how the `is` keyword works with union types but why doesn't it work on the conditional type based.

Comment: Does it work if you replace the function's return signature with `value is Test<"a">`?

Comment: [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Type predicates must be seen by the compiler as a narrowing of the parameter type; since `Test<T>` might possibly be `string` (and *not* `number | string`), then you cannot legally narrow it to `number`.  Otherwise it would let you call `ValueIsNumber<"b">("abc")` and return `value is number` when the input type is `string`.  You can replace `number` with `Extract<Type<T>, number>` or `Type<T> & number` to make it an accurate narrowing, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAJM8W).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Do note that this is very strange code; you can't infer `T` from a value of type `Test<T>`, so such inference will almost certainly fail when you call `valueIsNumber()` or `myFunc()`, in which case it falls back to `"a" | "b"` and your code falls back to essentially the non-conditional non-generic code [shown here](https://tsplay.dev/mpj3xw), which works fine.  Why are you trying to do it with generic conditional types?  Maybe you should give a [mre] that motivates it; right now it seems like a bizarre approach that hurts more than it helps.  How should we proceed here?

Comment: I simplified the case just to understand why it doesn't work ... my code is more complicated than this but respect the same idea ... I'm checking if your answer helps me and if not I'll try to better explain the problem ... thank you so much for your answer

Comment: Note that I didn't  *answer*; I just *commented*.  I will be happy to write up an actual answer if you confirm that I should do so.

Comment: No it's not necessary I tried to use heavily generics and conditional typing to avoid using common keys with different value to discriminate in type unions but it wasn't a good idea in any case because it made my types unusable ... thanks for your concern I accepted the way union discrimination works, it's ugly but ...